# Нужно сделать форму внесения данных в БД через html/php страницу

Tags: php, html, mysql

Допустим:
Есть база данных 'baza'
В ней есть таблица 'tablica'
В ней есть столбцы 'stolbets1', 'stolbets2', 'stolbets3', 'stolbets4', 'stolbets5'
Задача:
Сделать на php страницу форму обновления этих данных, при условии:

```
<input id="poziciya2" />
<input id="poziciya3" />
<input id="poziciya4" />
<input id="poziciya5" />
<button type="sumbmit" />
```

Само условие:
После заполнения некоторых граф и нажатии на кнопку - обновить данные в БД, где 'poziciya1' текст, что был в ней написан - точное совпадение с 'stolbets1'. Обновить именно эту строку 'poziciya2' в 'stolbets2' и так далее.

Comment: Так вы сами сделали что-то или просто просите решение?

Comment: Просто прошу решение. Не моя специализация, но сделать нужно. Я сделал саму базу, и первый столбец, по которому должно проверяться, всё остальное вносить уже буду  не я.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По интерфейсу сильно абстрактно, непонятно как эти данные будут обрабатываться.
Как данные будут выводиться? (На стороне сервера - PHP скрипт или на стороне клиента JavaScript, JavaScript библиотеки + AJAX).

В форме input или select?

В любом случае запрос будет обрабатываться на сервере - смотрим количество заполненных полей, делаем запрос к БД (каждый раз проверять все поля или только последнее). Как только все поля заполнены - добавляем в БД. По сути самая обычная форма, только вместо ошибок при неполном заполнении формы - подсказки со значениями.

Вот в принципе почти [решение](https://daruse.ru/zapis-v-bazu-dannyix-mysql-php-formu). Только проверять кол-во заполненных значений (самый простой вариант без всяких особых проверок и т.д., но общий смысл изложил):

```
if(isset($_POST['poziciya1']) && $_POST['poziciya1'] !== '') {
     if(isset($_POST['poziciya2']) && $_POST['poziciya2'] !== '') {
          if(isset($_POST['poziciya3']) && $_POST['poziciya3'] !== '') {
               // Добавление в БД
          }
          else {
               // выдаем значение для poziciya3
          }
     }
     else {
          // выдаем значение для poziciya2
     }
}
else {
     // ничего не заполнено
}
```

Comment: Извиняюсь, если написал недостаточно доступно, я тут новенький. Внутренний сайт для нашей компании должен собирать данные, которые выгружают наши сотрудники. Например мы собираемся на корпоратив и нужно выбрать куда едем. Они открывают страницу голосования. Там уже подтянут их логин, им нужно заполнить только одно поле input в котором написать, например "природа". После нажатия на сабмит данные передаются в БД в строку, которая точно совпадает с логином. Точно совпадение, к сожалению критично, т.к. в бд они должны все идти по определённому порядку, так бы через формы нашего кмс'а.